# Proving function complexity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

I am trying to prove the following: 
Let $$f(n)=\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{i \log i} $$  Where log denotes the natural logarithm. Show that: $$ f(n)=\Theta (\log \log n)$$

I am not sure how to go about showing this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What means that $\Theta$? Big 'O' notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Since $f(x)=x\log x$ is increasing over $[1,\infty)$ so
$$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{f(x)}\le \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{f(k)}\le \frac{1}{f(2)}+\int_3^\infty \frac{dx}{f(x-1)}$$